How to update the object's property value using Forge APIs
I have a model displayed in Forge Viewer that is retrieved from ACC/BIM360.
I want to update one of the property value associated with the object in the loaded model as well as in ACC/BIM360 model.
Is it possible to achieve this using the available Forge APIs?
I have gone through all the endpoints and services available. But seems that there is no API endpoint available to update the property value associated with object

It's possible using Design Automation API. Please check this tutorial
This blog explains uploading files from Design Automation to ACC.

Thanks for the suggestion, Varun! I'm already following the posts you suggested. It's been very helpful.
